# How to prevent accidently deleting important files as root user

Tags: linux, shell

I need to use root for the installation and maintenance for the database and application server that I am playing around with. The database and application server create files and directories in the /usr directory that I need to manipulate.I have accidentally deleted important files in /usr in the past , making the system act funny.I was wondering how to prevent this from happening in the future. I have a habit of rm -rf developed from years of non root user use.

I thought of moving /usr to /usr_bkp and creating a soft_link /usr to point to /usr_bkp. I am afraid that moving or removing /usr even temporarily will have unpredictable consequences. What is the best known method to avoid such errors.

Comment: Why was this down voted? I know that -i gives an interactive prompt to remove files but it does not work when coupled with -rf.

Comment: WHY are you working as the root user? If you must, use a regular user account and use `sudo` instead of a root shell. I find that typing the sudo reminds me that I am entering a root command.

Comment: Installation of databases and application server works with root user permissions. Many create files in the /usr directory. I have a force of habit  of typing -rf with rm . I try to be extra careful when working as root user but sometimes I get disctracted for a second and oops!! to late. I want to avoid such slippages like I mentioned in the original post and want some way to having these files safe against these accidents

Comment: How about not running as root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*I mostly work as root user these days and have accidentally deleted important files*": those two don't work together. Removing files by mistake is one of the actions that have immediate and visible consequences (there are others that might appear later and require lots of time to debug).

Create a separate user (this is what I'd suggest until gaining more XP) and give it [sudo](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) rights (the good thing is that extreme care is only required in *sudo* mode, not by default).

As for the 2nd part:

- I'm pretty sure that *symlinking* */usr* is not something that the *Linux* admin manual recommends
- `rm -rf /usr/SOME_FILES_OR_FOLDERS` when */usr* is a *symlink* to *usr_bkp* (or whatever its name could be), will still delete the files/folders located in the */usr* folder, so no protection there.
- The only change I see is that every time something from */usr* will be accessed, instead of the direct access, the *symlink* will have to be resolved (each time ?); (more operations, require more time -> performance decrease)
- (if i'm not missing something obvious,) doing the *symlink* thing would introduce some "traps" since `mv`, `ln`,... are *ELFs*  that (by default) reside in */usr/bin*, and the 1st command (`mv`) will succeed, but then you'll no longer have `ln` (unless specifying its full **new** path), or in other words "ROUText: ti-ai taiat craca :d ". Regarding running apps, I think you'll be OK (at most a reboot required).

So, considering the 4 items I advise not to use *root* (at least for now).

Comment: Indeed. the OP has manufactured a problem for himself (runs as root, can't stop typing `rm -rf`) and has conjured up some utterly wrong approaches to protect him from himself. Thanks for explaining why symlinks do nothing to help.

Comment: I need to use root for the installation and maintenance for the database and application server that I am playing around with. The database and application server create files and directories in the /usr directory that I need to manipulate

Comment: This doesn't prevent you for from doing that. You'll only have to use `sudo` before the command that want to execute, and of course the password (and if there are multiple commands it can get annoying). What I can say (I DO NOT KNOW WHY) is that on _RedHat_ based _Linux_ machines, once I enter `sudo` pwd, other `sudo` commands no longer ask for it (if executed in a certain??? amount of time).

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of root is to do everything he wants. However you could use the -i option to have to confirm to delete the files.

Comment: I know that -i gives an interactive prompt to remove files but it does not work when coupled with -rf.

Answer (score 0):

What x4rkz said but also if you're concerned of 'rm'ing files as root, create an alias in your shell's rc file to always confirm the removal of files.  In Bourne derivatives this can be accomplished with:

```
alias rm='/usr/bin/rm -i '
```

Test:

```
# alias rm='/usr/bin/rm -i'
# rm test
# /usr/bin/rm: remove regular empty file â€˜testâ€™? y
```

Of course, this won't help you if you write a script that doesn't first load that alias.

Another failure mode I've seen with new admins is misusing output redirection and overwriting a file.  In Bourne derivatives, you can set the 'NOCLOBBER' option in shell scripts to prevent this:

```
# set NOCLOBBER
```

This is not 100% portable so ensure this is supported before relying on it.

Answer (score 0):

OK so you are working with a database and an application.

Write a script. Then don't touch the files unless you use the script.

Just put into the script every operation that you need to do.

```
./my-script clean
./my-script install
./my-script run
etc...
```

This way the files will be deleted by clean, installed, and the application restarted the same way every time with no danger of deleting the wrong thing.

Also, consistency is something you want as a developer. No more wondering why the update failed because you forgot to copy the right files into place or forgot to remove the old binaries.